# QGIS2Web won't display OpenLayers but does display Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, qgis2web

I'm trying to make a web map. I have everything working fine in QGIS 2.18.15 (all point exist where they should and layers are all good), but when I try to make a web map with OpenLayers nothing shows up, either on the preview or on export. I can get a base map, but none of my shapes or points appear. When I choose the Leaflet option The points and shapes appear, but the points lose their gradation that I've defined in QGIS (more populated points are bigger and have a brighter hue in QGIS, but all points are the same size and colour in OpenLayers.)

Any help?

Comment: There are instructions on how to narrow down any problems you may experience with qgis2web in its Help tab, on the home page of the plugin's repo at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web, and as placeholder text when you open a new Github issue. Please follow those instructions to help get more information about the issue you've encountered. It's impossible to know what's wrong from the limited information you have provided so far.