# Is there an alternative to qgis2web?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis2web

My [qgis2web Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2web/) is not working, as I receive the error as you see below:

[image]

Basically, it's able to display layers in Leaflet, but not correctly enough. The problem is similar to these:

- [QGIS2Web won't display OpenLayers but does display Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276345/qgis2web-wont-display-openlayers-but-does-display-leaflet)
- [Python error when using qgis2web](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286913/python-error-when-using-qgis2web)

As I see on Github there is a lot of issues

- https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues

reading all the hints here it looks like the Plugin is no longer supported.

Is there any other counterpart, which I can use?

I would like to populate the GeoPackage layer as an interactive map (i.e. Leaflet or similar) with keeping all the colouration, labels, etc the same.

I tried to convert the GeoPackage layer into GeoJSON, but finally I got a separate layers, which in my geopackage were bounded in one group. When I uploaded it on http://geojson.io I saw everything in the greyscale.

How can I show my geopackage layer interactively?

Comment: You can Try QGisCloud

Comment: As [Tom's note](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/923) makes clear he has plenty of time for people to pay him to fix these problems, just no time to fix them for free just now. Or you can fix the issue yourself - it looks like max is going to 0 for some reason

Comment: QGIS server has some geopackage compatibility.  See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34391  I have no experience with this, so can't say it would work.

Comment: It is most likely something weird with one of your layers.  You should head over to https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues and add your issue, I usually try and help most people.  I find it easier to help people over there. Does Qgis2web have a lot of issues?  Well, sure but no more or less than a typical project.

Comment: It would be easier to help to see your data and project files.  Can you provide samples?

Comment: Please ask one specific question, not multiple ones, in your post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many alternatives to qgis2web, including QGIS Cloud, Lizmap, ArcGIS online, Mapbox, CARTO, Google Maps, MapTiler, deegree, MapBender, and others (Github certainly used to present uploaded GeoJSON as a Leaflet map, though I am not sure whether this is still the case). Most paid services have low-usage free tiers.

qgis2web has never been supported. Without a third-party support contract, QGIS itself has never been supported, and never will be. The same applies to all open-source software. No money is charged to buy or to use it, so, without another contractual mechanism in place, there is by definition no support.

As Ian Turton says in his comment above, you can purchase support, development, or bug-fixing from many commercial companies. I am not one of them.

I hope you accept this answer. It is extremely important to accept that the contractual model when using open-source is completely different to commercially-licensed software.

### Update

I've committed a fix for the Leaflet export error you experienced: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/commit/3aeeb2d10c6de0d7c5d784800de1644a40d924ca

The issue will therefore be fixed in the next release of qgis2web, or you can download current master branch from the Github repo (or apply that commit's patch yourself to your local copy). Thanks for finding and reporting the bug.

If you make any changes to your local copy of a plugin, you need to reload QGIS to load the new code (or use the Plugin Reloader plugin).

Comment: I've accepted. However you posted also the payable platforms. Could you list this "many many others"? if possible?

Comment: @MKR: Don`t panic!

Comment: Tom Chadwin is doing an excellent job and with a little luck he can do it in the future!

Comment: @Tom Chadwin,
It still comes with the same problem - I can't create the map from OpenLayers level.   \olStyleScripts.py", line 78, in exportStyles bufferColor,
\olStyleScripts.py", line 193, in getLabelFormat if max != 0 - float division by 0

Comment: @MKR Please open a new issue at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/. Someone can take a look at the issue then - we need to have your project and layer files to be able to recreate the issue, and the repo is a more appropriate place to do bug reporting/fixing.

Comment: OK, I restarted QGIS and it looks, that error itself has been fixed. The problem is, that the map comes with nothing. I will raise the issue. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: My apologies - I forgot to tell you to restart QGIS, which reloads the new plugin code. I'll amend the answer.